# How to check if array has required keys in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I know PHP has a lot of functions for arrays, but I am not sure which one to use know, or if custom function is needed.

I have a function that accepts arrays, and I would need those arrays passed as arguments to have certain keys. When an array is passed, I would need to check if the form of the arrays is proper, example:

```
<?php function( $array ) {
      // Array needs to have form Array('server'=>, 'database'=>,'username'=>
      I could check it as "array_key_exists", but it seems too long, there must be a
     a way to iterate throught arguments
     $template = Array('server'=>'', 'database'=>'','username'=>'');

     foreach( $array AS $key => $value ) {
       //Somehow compare if array $array includes keys as $template
```

Is there any way to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: [`Array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) might be useful here.

Comment: Thank you, very simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

- [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) as mario mentioned

  ```
  $template = array('server', 'database', 'username');
  if (array_intersect_key($template, array_keys($array)) == $template) {
    // all parameters were passed
  }
  ```
- [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc):

  ```
  $template = array('server', 'database', 'username');
  if (empty(array_diff($template, array_keys($array)))) { 
    // all parameters got passed
  }
  ```

  For PHP < 5.5.0: replace the IF construct with `count(array_diff($template, $array)) == 0`

Comment: +1. Just realized my answer and the second part of your answer is almost identical. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I've fixed a bug in both code samples thanks to your answer! I was missing the `array_keys` parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array_intersect( array_keys($array), array_keys($template)) == array_keys($template)){
  // do your business
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) and [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys)

```
function check_keys(array $array) {
    $template = array('server', 'database', 'username');
    return (count(array_diff($template, array_keys($array))) == 0);
}
```